# My gear idles after inactivity of some hours in Bronze plan

Tags: openshift

I'm evaluating openshift and just upgraded to Bronze plan. However my gear keeps idling after a few hours of inactivity. What should I check?

Comment: If you are at evaluation phase, be aware that what you are using is OpenShift V2. This is being superseded by OpenShift V3. V2 is currently in developer preview. You may want to consider looking at V3 instead as it is quite different to V2. Details at https://www.openshift.com/devpreview/

Comment: I'm aware of that. As v3 is not available yet, and my project is about going to production, I have to stick with v2.

Comment: Just be aware that V2 will eventually be phased out. There has been no timetable announced for that, but once V3 is generally available then you can expect that something will be said about it.